# viewing duplicate records and multiple where clause error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue where I am looking for duplicate user id's and need 2 where clauses. Unfortunately the query below is throwing me an error. How can I view duplicate user id's with the criteria I am wanting?

```
select user_id, 
       order_placed, 
       downloaded, 
       template 
  from orders
GROUP BY 
       user_id, 
       order_placed, 
       downloaded, 
       template 
where (modified >= '2014-01-01' and downloaded = 'N' )
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `WHERE` **before** `GROUP BY`, right after `FROM`.
That should work:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       order_placed, 
       downloaded, 
       template,
       COUNT(*) 
  FROM orders
 WHERE (    modified  >= '2014-01-01' 
        and downloaded = 'N' )
GROUP BY 
       user_id, 
       order_placed, 
       downloaded, 
       template 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I had that issue and yours works perfect as well.